# 16-bit x86 assembler, trouble drawing blue to screen using 8 -bit memory stored variable for color?

Tags: assembly, memory, nasm, dos, x86-16

The following code compiles and runs fine on *Xubuntu 16.04* with 
these commands in *bash shell*

`nasm blue.asm -fbin -oblue.com`

`dosbox ./blue.com -exit`

The problem I'm having is on line 20 
`mov     al, 1;byte [blue]`

where if I use this instead 
`mov     al, byte [blue]`

the program draws a sort of burgundy to the screen instead of blue. It works normally for using ***1*** which is the color code in the 8-bit palette here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_color_attributes

Here's the full code, feel free to let me know if anything else is wrong with it though.

```
org 00h
bits 16       

section .data             

    blue:    db       1  

section .text
MAIN:

AsyncKeyInput:      

    mov     al, 13h
    int     10h
    ; Segment a000h
    mov     ax, 0a000h
    mov     es, ax
    ; Offset 0
    xor     di, di
    mov     al, 1;byte [blue]
    ; Looplength (320*200)/2 = 7d00
    mov     cx, 7d00h

hplot:
    mov [ es: di], al       ;set pixel to colour
    inc di          ;move to next pixel
    loop hplot      

    mov     ah, 1          ;Get the State of the keyboard buffer
    int     16h            ;key press
    jz      AsyncKeyInput ;if not zero then exit the program 

    ;exit program
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
ret
```

Comment: `org 00` or `org 0x100`? `int 0x80` is an exit system call not a DOS exit, A COM program should work with just the `ret`

Comment: I think it's `org 00` but that's the default right? So no need to even declare it? Should it be `0x100`? what's the difference, it's the stack size right?

Comment: DOS COM programs are at offset 0x100 .

Comment: I get it, so when I use that `blue` it adds `0x100` to the address?

Comment: All the offsets of variables will be relative to 0x100 instead of 0x00 with my change - yes. 100h or 0x100 are of course same thing. both are HEX.

Comment: But I defined it at `0` so there is no offset, or does the compiler ignore it and use `0x100` anyway and that causes the `blue` to add to `0x100`  to get `0x101` or something close?

Comment: Ok got it to work it `org 100h` instead of what I used. You can answer this below and get credit if you want!

Comment: If you set it to 0 all offsets for variables like `blue` will be relative to a 0 origin point. With .COM programs when they are loaded by DOS they actually are started at offset 0x100 in the segment. The bytes between 0x00 and 0x100 are the [PSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix).

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem is to properly set the program segment prefix to `org 100h` for com programs. Here's the corrected code below.

```
org 100h
bits 16       

section .data             

    blue:    db       1h     

section .text
MAIN:

AsyncKeyInput:      

    mov     al, 13h
    int     10h
    ; Segment a000h
    mov     ax, 0a000h
    mov     es, ax
    ; Offset 0
    xor     di, di
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     al, byte [blue]
    ; Looplength (320*200)/2 = 7d00
    mov     cx, 7d00h

hplot:
    mov [ es: di], al       ;set pixel to colour
    inc di          ;move to next pixel
    loop hplot      

    mov     ah, 1          ;Get the State of the keyboard buffer
    int     16h            ;key press
    jz      AsyncKeyInput ;if not zero then exit the program 

    ;text mode
    mov     ax, 0003h
    int     10h         
ret
```

Comment: There is one more (big) problem. The COM doesn't have any sections, it's simply <64kiB binary loaded by DOS from 0x0100 offset into first free segment. So at the moment the `blue db 1` defines also the first instruction to be executed, which a quick search through web disassemblers shows as "db 0x1", so I'm not sure how CPU handles it, probably as some undefined code. Drop the useless ".section" headers, and start the code immediately after `org 0x0100`, put variables in the middle/at end of code, where they will not get executed by accident. And probably read something about DOS COM files.

Comment: Also other minor problem, the start of code with `mov     al, 13h` `int 10h` is not a correct way how to set 13h gfx mode. You must set also `ah` to zero ("set gfx mode service"), you just get lucky under dosbox, that the their DOS leaves zero in `ah` after loading the COM. So `mov ax,13h` is the correct way how to load AH=0, AL=0x13.  (and then the label `AsyncKeyInput` is probably not placed well, causing re-init of gfx mode every time).

Comment: @Ped7g "The COM doesn't have any sections, it's simply <64kiB binary loaded by DOS from 0x0100 offset into first free segment. " Should I put all my data variables after the code section too then?

Comment: @Ped7g could you maybe also suggest some other way to do the same thing without dosbox on linux, just wondering if this is the only way?

Comment: I tried getting rid of the sections and putting the `blue` at the end and removing the first two lines and that works, but setting `ah` to zero causes flickering!

Comment: Sure, if you reinit graphics mode every time, and then draw it to blue, it will flicker. If you don't set the `ah`, it's set to *something* from the later `int 16h`, and you are calling random services of `int 10h` with `al=13h`... for some reason you are lucky enough to not call something truly crashing/damaging, so it "works" for you, but it's simply not correct. You need to change your main loop logic, if you don't want flicker, setting the graphics mode just once probably.

Comment: About linux: there's no simple way to get such direct video ram access under linux (AFAIK), probably one of easiest would be to load some library similar to SDL (probably picking the one with simplest API), and call that from ASM, or even create simple C++ skeleton preparing the environment for ASM code (initializing video, controllers, etc.. any OS/HW stuff wrapped in C/C++), and then doing in ASM just the pure algorithms and writing to the already prepared buffers to produce gfx.